# Creating a belongs to association on a two way Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, rails-activerecord

### **QUESTION:**

### How would I create an association be between the a new model: `post.rb` and existing 2 models: category + work models? And how would I pluck the `post.rb`'s attribute `content:text`, so that I may add a unique post from the `work#new` -> `_form` partial

I have a many to many relationship between `work` and `category` models `:through categorywork`

I would like to add a new model called `post` with an attribute called `content:text` I would like the association of this model to be, as such: **Every Work has many categories, each category inside work has a unique post.**

Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly draw out or explain this association, so I will draw a makeshift schema below for reference along with pictures.

e.g: textual reference

**One Work**

- name: project A

**Many Categories**

- *project A* -> category name:UxD
- *project A* -> category name:ID
- *project A* -> category name:Development

**Unique Post**

- *project A -> UxD*         -> post content:lorem ipsum 1
- *project A -> ID*          -> post content:lorem ipsum 2
- *project A -> Development* -> post content:lorem ipsum 3

e.g: graphical reference

**work#index**

[image: work#index]

---

**work#show?category1**

[image: work#show?category1]

---

**work#show?category2**

[image: work#show?category2]

---

---

---

---

### [Models](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/tree/master/app/models)

**How would I write the association to connect `post.rb` to the preexisting many-to-many relationship**

**[category.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/models/category.rb)**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  has_many  :categoryworks
  has_many :works, :through => :categoryworks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :works
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :category_ids, :svg

end
```

**[work.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/models/work.rb)**

```
class Categorywork < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many  :categoryworks
  has_many :categories, :through => :categoryworks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
  attr_accessible :name, :subtitle, :category_ids, :svg
end
```

**[categorywork.rb](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/models/categorywork.rb)**

```
class Categorywork < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to    :category
  belongs_to    :work
  attr_accessible :category_id, :work_id
end
```

---

### [Controllers](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/tree/master/app/controllers)

[works_controller](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/controllers/works_controller.rb):  *example of many to many association in the new controller*

**What would I add to `work_controller.rb` to gain access of the `post.rb` attr content:text ?**

```
 def new
    @work = Work.new

    @all_categories = Category.all
    @work_category = @work.categoryworks.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @work }
   end
 end
```

---

### [Views](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/views/works/new.html.erb)

[_form Partial](https://github.com/matthewharwood/blog/blob/master/app/views/works/_form.html.erb): *showing the many-to-many between categories and Works*

**What would I write to add the `post.rb` attr content:text to each check box this form**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= hidden_field_tag "work[category_ids][]", nil %>
  <% Category.all.each do |category|  %>
    <%= check_box_tag "work[category_ids][]", category.id, @work.category_ids.include?(category.id), id: dom_id(category) %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %><br>
  <% end  %>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite get it, but I think add `belongs_to :post` to `Categorywork ` should solve your problem. am i right?

Comment: It may but what would I add to controller and views to get the Works _form to beable to add posts?